# How do I open a link in Safari from TikTok Webview?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, url

I insert a link in the TikTok account profile and I want the users who click on it to be taken to Safari instead of Webview. Which is similar to intent:// on android. I tried to search for info on this for a long time, but none of the suggestions helped: "http://" links still open in tiktok webview, ftp does not work either.
The only thing I could do is to open third-party applications when I click on a link from TikTok. The following JS code helped me in this:

```
var redirect = function (location) {
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.setAttribute('src', location);
    iframe.setAttribute('width', '1px');
    iframe.setAttribute('height', '1px');
    iframe.setAttribute('position', 'absolute');
    iframe.setAttribute('top', '0');
    iframe.setAttribute('left', '0');
    document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);
    iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
    iframe = null;
};

setTimeout(function () {
    redirect('http://itunes.apple.com/app/id');
}, 25);

redirect('custom-uri://');
```

I used this code to open Twitter and other apps with my URL scheme. But I don't know how to fix this code under Safari. Is there a similar solution for Safari?
I also tried to open Google Chrome with this code with its URL scheme "googlechrome://" and "googlechromes://". But for some reason it didn't work.

Comment: Same question here...